# $E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\max_{1 \leq k\leq d}R_k}]=\sum_{k=1}^d(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1 \leq i_1<...<i_k \leq d}E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min_{ 1 \leq p \leq k} R_{i_p}}]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

$R$ and $Q$ are two stopping times for a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_k)_k$ and $ X \in L^1.$ We can prove that (and will be used below in the proof):
[$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}_{Q}]|\mathcal{F}_R]=E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min(R,Q)}]=E[E[X|\mathcal{F}_R]|\mathcal{F}_Q]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051773/eex-mathcalf-q-mathcalf-r-ex-mathcalf-minr-q)

We want to prove that the following holds, almost surely,
$$E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\max(R,Q)}]+E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min(R,Q)}]=E[X|\mathcal{F}_R]+E[X|\mathcal{F}_Q].$$

One way to prove it:

$\mathcal{F}_{\max(R,Q)}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_R \cup \mathcal{F}_Q)=\sigma(\{K_1 \cap K_2, (K_1,K_2) \in \mathcal{F}_Q \times \mathcal{F}_R\}).$

$E[X|\mathcal{F}_R],E[X|\mathcal{F}_Q],E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\max(R,Q)}],E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min(R,Q)}]$ are all $\mathcal{F}_{\max(R,Q)}$-measurable.

So it's sufficient to prove that for $K_1 \in \mathcal{F}_{R},K_2 \in \mathcal{F}_{Q},$ $$E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 }]+E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2}E[X|{\mathcal{F}}_{\min(R,Q)}]]=E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2}E[X|\mathcal{F}_R]]+E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2}E[X|\mathcal{F}_Q]] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

We have :

$E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 }]+E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2}E[X|{\mathcal{F}}_{\min(R,Q)}]]=E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R \leq Q\} }]+E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R > Q\} }]+E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap {\{R \leq Q\}}}E[X|{\mathcal{F}}_{\min(R,Q)}]]+E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2\{R>Q\}}E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min(R,Q)}]].$

Since $K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R \leq Q\} \in \mathcal{F}_Q,K_1 \cap K_2 \cap\{R>Q\} \in \mathcal{F}_R,$ then

$E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R \leq Q\} }]=E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R \leq Q\} }E[X|\mathcal{F}_Q]],$

$
E[X1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R > Q\} }]=E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap \{R > Q\} }E[X|\mathcal{F}_R]],$

$
E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap {\{R \leq Q\}}}E[X|{\mathcal{F}}_{\min(R,Q)}]]=E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2 \cap {\{R \leq Q\}}}E[X|{\mathcal{F}}_{R}]]$,

$
E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2\{R>Q\}}E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min(R,Q)}]]=E[1_{K_1 \cap K_2\{R>Q\}}E[X|\mathcal{F}_{Q}]]$

In other word $(1)$ holds, to conclude using $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.

Since the above is true, the following should also hold (by induction...): $R_1,...,R_d$ are stopping times for a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ then $$E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\max_{1 \leq k \leq d}R_k}]=\sum_{k=1}^d(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1 \leq i_1<...<i_k \leq d}E[X|\mathcal{F}_{\min_{ 1 \leq p \leq k} R_{i_p}}]$$

Comment: Wow. Looks intuitive enough, but I’ve never seen how to condition on the **max** of two stopping times. The minimum, on the other hand, is easy. Would be interesting to see any approach.

Comment: Do not now if there is another approach, maybe using stopping time on the martingale $(E[X|\mathcal{F}_n])_n$

Comment: The maximum $T$ of two stopping times is not a stopping time in general, is it? I did not practice probability for a while so I may be wrong... But if I'm right, is $\mathcal{F}_T$ well defined if $T$ is not a stopping time? (maybe another idiot question).

Comment: Ah no sorry, the max is a stopping time.

Comment: Let $ X_t=\mathsf{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}_t] $, then
$ \mathsf{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}_{R\vee S}]=X_{R\vee S}=X_R+X_S-X_{R\wedge S} 
=\mathsf{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}_R]+\mathsf{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}_S] -\mathsf{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}_{R\wedge S}]$